# Asterisk::AMI module

Tags: perl, asterisk, telephony

I'm learning about Asterisk::AMI module in perl to connect to asterisk. While running the following program I can't connect to asterisk. can anyone give me solution to solve this issue?.

```
use Asterisk::AMI;
my $astman = Asterisk::AMI->new(PeerAddr        =>      '127.0.0.1', #Remote host address
                                PeerPort        =>      '5038',      #Remote host port
                                                                     #AMI is available on TCP port 5038 if you enable it in manager.conf. 
                                Username        =>      'admin',     #Username to access the AMI

                                Secret          =>      'supersecret' #Secret used to connect to AMI
                                );

die "Unable to connect to asterisk" unless ($astman);

my $action = $astman->({ Action => 'Command',
                         Command => 'sip show peers'
                       });

print $action;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're trying to get a telephony stackexchange site started.  If you're interested, please consider committing: [StackExchange Telephony Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12932/telephony?referrer=t19aZKsEkDYFK9yUPwMC_g2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should show errors/warnings if you include:

```
use warnings;
```

at the start of your script.

Answer (score 1):

I've been passing through the same problem
Then I discovered that I had to configure 
the user in /etc/asterisk/manager.conf file

Just like this example
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+manager.conf

you will get success;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comman here:
'$action = $astman->({...'
**it should be**
'$action = $astman->send_action({...'